# Can't start React dev server on port 80

Tags: reactjs, sudo, port80

[image]

I used to be able to start React dev server on port 80. I just modified the package.json and ran it with sudo. I stopped developing for a few months, installed a fresh linux, and now I can't run it anymore. I run it with sudo but I still get the same error. Any ideas?